# Org attachment : how to attach a directory?

Tags: org-mode, org-attach

the main question is in the title

Also:

- if it is impossible, why? Can we solve the problem?
- if it is possible, how?

I made some tests by adding directly a folder in the attachment folder, then I inserted a link towards this folder thanks to
[[Attachment:nameofdirectory/][descriptionhere]].
This link works, but why the functionality to add a folder is not available ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use the `move` or `symlink` mtehod, you should be able to attach a directory (always subject to the underlying permissions). `copy` does not work because the underlying implementation uses `copy-file` which cannot copy a directory; `link` does not work because   of hardlink limitations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A symlink is not why I search (if it's possible), ans the "move" method don't work too, I have this error : "org-attach-attach : File already exists: /home/name/whereIsTheHealine/data/XX/XXXX-...-XXX". Possible to change the fonction with the method "copy" (to call, for exemple "copy-directory")

Comment: Edit : same error with symlink. Version of org mode (maybe the problem) : 9.5.3. Emacs 27.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussions with developers of org mode, it is normally possible (with an update of org-mode). However, you can just copy and paste this function in your configuration for it to work (normally).

```
(defun org-attach-attach (file &optional visit-dir method)
"Move/copy/link FILE into the attachment directory of the current outline node.

  If VISIT-DIR is non-nil, visit the directory with `dired'.
  METHOD may be `cp', `mv', `ln', `lns' or `url' default taken from
  `org-attach-method'."
    (interactive
     (list
      (read-file-name "File to keep as an attachment: "
                      (or (progn
                            (require 'dired-aux)
                            (dired-dwim-target-directory))
                          default-directory))
      current-prefix-arg
      nil))
    (setq method (or method org-attach-method))
    (when (file-directory-p file)
      (setq file (directory-file-name file)))
    (let ((basename (file-name-nondirectory file)))
      (let* ((attach-dir (org-attach-dir 'get-create))
             (attach-file (expand-file-name basename attach-dir)))
        (cond
         ((eq method 'mv) (rename-file file attach-file))
         ((eq method 'cp)
          (if (file-directory-p file)
              (copy-directory file attach-file nil nil t)
            (copy-file file attach-file)))
         ((eq method 'ln) (add-name-to-file file attach-file))
         ((eq method 'lns) (make-symbolic-link file attach-file))
         ((eq method 'url) (url-copy-file file attach-file)))
        (run-hook-with-args 'org-attach-after-change-hook attach-dir)
        (org-attach-tag)
        (cond ((eq org-attach-store-link-p 'attached)
               (push (list (concat "attachment:" (file-name-nondirectory attach-file))
                           (file-name-nondirectory attach-file))
                     org-stored-links))
              ((eq org-attach-store-link-p t)
               (push (list (concat "file:" file)
                           (file-name-nondirectory file))
                     org-stored-links))
              ((eq org-attach-store-link-p 'file)
               (push (list (concat "file:" attach-file)
                           (file-name-nondirectory attach-file))
                     org-stored-links)))
        (if visit-dir
            (dired attach-dir)
          (message "File %S is now an attachment" basename)))))
```

Comment: Can you highlight how the function you posted is different from what Org mode distributes? Also please add a link to the discussion you had on the Org mode mailing list.

Comment: Normally it is the same function. Sorry if I misspoke: if you don't want to / can't update org-mode, just copy and paste this function into the emacs configuration file (and load it after loading org-mode of course)
The link for the discussion is [here](https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2022-06/msg00126.html), but the discussion is not complete (not exactly why).